# How to assign variable name in loop function

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a function that returns the squared values in three columns in a Dataframe specified in a list. I'm trying to loop though these columns in the following way. Each column ['Close_large', 'Close_mid', 'Close_small'] is part of a dataframe that contains float values.

```
def x_squared(DataFrame):
    '''squares all the values in columns'''
    columns = ['Close_large', 'Close_mid', 'Close_small']
    for columns in DataFrame:
        DataFrame[columns + '_sqr'] = [x**2 for x in columns]
    return DataFrame
```

FULL ERROR:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-791ae28fe2b9> in <module>
----> 1 df = x_squared(df)

<ipython-input-3-8db48cd5ae20> in x_squared(DataFrame)
     32     columns = ['Close_large', 'Close_mid', 'Close_small']
     33     for columns in DataFrame:
---> 34         DataFrame[columns + '_std'] = [x**2 for x in columns]
     35     return DataFrame
     36 

<ipython-input-3-8db48cd5ae20> in <listcomp>(.0)
     32     columns = ['Close_large', 'Close_mid', 'Close_small']
     33     for columns in DataFrame:
---> 34         DataFrame[columns + '_std'] = [x**2 for x in columns]
     35     return DataFrame
     36 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'int'
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: How can square string value?

Comment: The columns contain float values that I want to square

Comment: `columns` is a list of strings. What does `DataFrame` look like?

Comment: i don't see float value in this `['Close_large', 'Close_mid', 'Close_small']`

Comment: So not only is my name assignment wrong but also the entire loop function?

Comment: Probably, and please provide full error trace in your questions because where you say the problem is, is not really where it is... So provide the full error

Comment: i think he needs to edit like this  for x in df[close_large]

Comment: You do seem to be misunderstanding how the Python `for` loop works. There are numerous online tutorials that can help.

Comment: @Deadpool `columns` is not the given list actually. it is overriden in the `for` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can square the entire column after accessing it by name.

try this:

```py
def x_squared(DataFrame):
    '''squares all the values in columns'''
    columns = ['Close_large', 'Close_mid', 'Close_small']
    for col in columns:
        DataFrame[col + '_sqr'] = DataFrame[col]**2
    return DataFrame
```

Comment: P.S naming you parameter `DataFrame` can be confusing, as `DataFrame` is also the type's name

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you very much!! If you do not mind me asking, why didn't my function work? Thank you for the tip, highly appreciate it!

Comment: @MisterButter it had to do with how you used your `for` loop. notice you iterated `DataFrame` while I iterate over `columns`.